# How to generate SQL from Request?

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, symfony

Currently I use next approach for retreiving data according to request:

```
/**
 * @QueryParam(name="filters", nullable=true, map=true, description="Filter by fields. Must be an array ie. &filters[id]=3")
 */
public function cgetAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
    $filters = $paramFetcher->get('filters') ?: [];

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository($this->entityClassName())
        ->findBy($filters);
    return $entities;
}
```

But I need [something like this](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#filter-limit): specify complex conditions in GET request, for example

- `?filter={"where":{"or":[{"id":1},{"id":2},...,{"id":20"},{"id":21}]}}`
- `?filter[where][date][gt]=2014-04-01T18:30:00.000Z`
- `?filter={"where": {"keywords": {"inq": ["foo", "bar"]}}}`
- `?filter[where][and][0][title]=My%20Post&filter[where][and][1][content]=Hello`
- etc

and get data from repository in according to this request.

Does exist any bundle for Symfony for this purpose? Will be glad for any advice.

Comment: You realise it applies to mongodb only?

Comment: not similar, but found this interesting https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters ( yes, its based on Symfony )

Comment: @Alex Blex, I use only PostgreSQL.

Comment: For DQL queries filters will look like `?filter = where a.id = 1 or a.id = 2 or …. a.id = 20 or a.id = 21` , `?filter = where a.date >= ‘2014-04-01 18:30:00’` etc. assuming table alias is `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [LexikFormFilterBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle), it's made for this use case, building form filters and then build a doctrine query from this form filter.

You'll find [a complete example here](http://www.ahcobos.com/content/form-filters-symfony2-complete-example).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it later

Comment: I had no time to try it yet. I will try it on this week

Comment: I try to use this bundle. I created ItemFilterType: https://github.com/Qeti/Karika/blob/8cff33110613c0410383e1c63424a15cb0fa348c/src/Karika/CoreBundle/Filter/ItemFilterType.php and changed `cget()` action of controller: https://github.com/Qeti/Karika/blob/8cff33110613c0410383e1c63424a15cb0fa348c/src/Karika/CoreBundle/Controller/Api/ApiController.php#L98 But I cant find what url format I must use for filtering by id. This has no effect: `/api/products?item_filter={"id":"3"}`. @Veve, May you help?